# Comparing Query- redundancy

Tags: mysql

```
select DISTINCT B.`Product#`,
                B.`Contact Email Address`,
CASE when A.`Product#` IS NULL then 'Yes' ELSE 'NO' END  as New customer
from `Table B` as B
LEFT JOIN `Table A` as A 
ON A. `product#`= B.`product#`
```

What wrong in my query. I see lot of product # is repeated. Also it says "Yes" when Product # is there in Table B but none in table A..

Comment: Can't really help you if you tables are called `TABLE A` and `TABLE B`.  At least use a more meaningful table names, or give a description of the relationship between table A and table B.

Comment: As I see one of the tables contains info about customers, and another about products. But where does the relation between customers and products is stored? Show full DDLs for both tables with description for each field meaning, sample data and the result which you need for this data.

Comment: Putting spaces in variable (table, field) names in SQL is a recipe for disaster and will make porting the application to another RDBMS difficult if ever required. Just use the `_` (underscore) character as a word separator - called python_case.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this for the yes/no:

```
IF(EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM A WHERE product_no = B.product_no ), 'Yes', 'No') AS NewCustomer
```